# No margin in Navigation Drawer item on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-navigationview, android-vectordrawable

I am implementing the android's default Navigation Drawer Activity. Its working perfectly in **API >= Lollipop** but in case of **Pre Lollipop Devices** it is working but there are no margins for item icon and item TextView badge.

To make it easy to understand please check the screenshot below:
[image]

I tried to search the answer for the issue but I haven't find any solution.

Here is my **drawer_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#0B0A12"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my menu_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Dashboard" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_appointments"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_appointments"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
            android:title="My Appointments" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_patients"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_patients"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
            android:title="My Customers" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pat_ref"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_pat_ref"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
            android:title="Customer Referrals" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pat_rew"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_pat_rew"
            android:title="Customer Reviews" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_doc_ref"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_doc_ref"
            android:title="Business Owner Referrals"
            android:titleCondensed="Business Referrals"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_envelope"
            android:title="Messages" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="My Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I am using vector image assest for the navigation item ico. Here is one of them ic_dashboard.xml

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="634.0"
    android:viewportWidth="583.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#BBBBBE" android:pathData="M93.5,155.3c20.6,-14.8 41.6,-29.1 62.4,-43.7c22.3,-15.8 44.5,-31.8 66.8,-47.7c20.8,-14.9 41.7,-29.7 62.5,-44.5c8.1,-5.8 12.6,-5.9 20.6,-0c19.1,13.9 38.5,27.5 57.8,41c22.6,15.8 44.8,32 67.2,48c22.8,16.2 46.3,31.6 68.8,48.2c4.6,3.4 -8.5,-6.2 11.1,8.4c18.7,13.1 37.3,26.2 56,39.4c6.3,4.5 6.3,12 3.8,15.6c-4,5.9 -11.7,6.8 -17.7,2.5c-15.4,-11.1 -30.7,-22.1 -46.9,-33.6c0,104.9 0,209.1 0,313.3c-140.3,0 -280.7,0 -421,0c0,-104.1 0,-208.3 0,-313.1c-10.9,7.7 -21.4,15.1 -31.9,22.5c-5.3,3.8 -10.4,7.8 -15.8,11.4c-6.2,4.1 -13.5,2.5 -17.1,-3.4c-3,-4.8 -0.8,-11.5 5,-15.5M295,480c61.2,0 122.3,-0.1 183.5,0.1c4.5,0 5.6,-1.1 5.6,-5.6C484,375.8 484,277.2 484,178.5c0,-1 -0.1,-2 0,-3c0.1,-1.6 -0.5,-2.5 -2,-3.5c-13.9,-9.8 -27.5,-20 -41.5,-29.7c-21.7,-15 -43.2,-30.4 -64.6,-45.7c-26.1,-18.7 -52.3,-37 -78.5,-55.6c-1.5,-1.1 -2.4,-1.1 -3.9,-0c-15,10.8 -30.1,21.4 -45.1,32.1c-25.6,18.2 -51.1,36.5 -76.8,54.7c-19.7,13.9 -39.5,27.7 -59.2,41.5c-3.8,2.6 -5.6,5.7 -5.6,10.8c0.2,98.3 0.2,196.7 0.1,295c-0,4.1 0.9,5.1 5.1,5.1C173,480 234,480 295,480z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#BBBBBE" android:pathData="M295.5,402c-18.3,0 -36.6,0 -55,-0c-6.8,-0 -11.6,-4.6 -11.6,-11.1c0,-6.1 4.9,-10.9 11.3,-10.9c36.8,-0 73.6,-0.1 110.4,0c6.8,0 11.5,4.9 11.3,11.3c-0.2,6.3 -4.9,10.6 -11.5,10.6C332.2,402 313.9,402 295.5,402z"/>
</vector>
```

Please guide how to provide the margins in Pre Lollipop devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set padding dynamically like below:

Check for the device's api and if it is less than lollipop then apply below code,

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
((NavigationMenuView)navigationView.getChildAt(0)).setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

You need to set padding to **NavigationMenuView** instead of **NavigationView**.

The above code is just example to set padding of child available at position Zero.

Hope it helps you.